# Averaging SVM and GLM results: sensible or stupid?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, svm, model-averaging

I have taken two different approaches to calculate probability: using a GLM and an SVM. They are giving slightly different results (which is understandable, they are completely different approaches). Both methods are proving to be generally accurate though and doing a similar job with predictions.

Given that it's hard to pick which method is better, I was just wondering if there would be any value in averaging the two results eg if item A has probably 0.65 of occurring according to SVM and 0.71 according to GLM, then take 0.68 as the probability.

Does this sound ok - getting the benefit of both a frequentist approach and a ML approach? Or is it just bad stats with no real basis?

Comment: yes, it's 100% sensible, though I think most people, rather than straight up averaging it, would do some kind of weighted average based on how accurate each method is; i.e. if the GLM is twice as accurate as the SVM  weight its probs twice as much (so in your example our prob would be (2*0.71+0.65)/3=0.69, which is nice). In your case if the accuracies are similar it won't make a difference but it might to the reader coming here from Google.

Comment: "*both a frequentist approach and a ML approach*" << No relevant distinction between the two... "both a frequentist approach and a Bayesian approach" or "*both a simple heuristic approach and an ML approach*" would be a more relevant distinction.

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Comment: If it is a non-linear SVM, you may want to try kernel logistic regression, which is essentially the "kernel trick" applied to a GLM.  I have found these rather useful (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4371217 - pre-print here: http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/publications/pdf/ijcnn2007a.pdf )

Comment: @JohnMadden: *especially* for people arriving from Google (or from the HNQ list), I would like to point out that estimating "optimal" weights does not necessarily improve performance over simple unweighted averaging. This phenomenon has been called the "forecast combination puzzle" in the forecasting literature. [Claeskens et al. (2016, *IJF*)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2015.12.005) provide an explanation: estimating the weights introduces another source of variation, which directly carries through to more variable predictions. It's a good idea to also try unweighted averages.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thanks for that link, isn't it so cool how digging deeper into things often advocates for the "naive" approach?

Comment: @usεr11852 allow me to disagree. A frequentist approach must satisfy some frequentist property (an asymptotic frequentist would instead satisfy this property asymptotically), such as "unbiased estimator with least variance". ML approaches are not motivated by such properties (necessarily).

Comment: @JohnMadden OK :) Because I somehow suspect we are splitting hairs here, can you please give an example? Are you think something like SVMs under a Maximal-Margin classifier view? Pretty much any ML and Stats (Freq. or Bayes) approach can be viewed as "data-driven inference" this is where I was aiming at. (Also we do use "biased" estimators (e.g. with ridge regression) just we formally control the Bias-Variance trade-off.)

Comment: @usεr11852 "splitting hairs" is how I earn a living ;) Neural nets are a great example: we don't have much theory at all about how they behave "in the long run". On the other hand, I know that a 95% CI, for, say, a generalized additive mixed model is supposed to cover the true function 95% of the time for large enough samples (a frequentist property).

Comment: @JohnMadden Ah... I suppose those EA gaming royalties aren't cutting it any longer. :D I think in "in the long-run" point is eroding, for example, works from the last 5 years like ["Simple and Scalable Predictive Uncertainty Estimation using Deep Ensembles"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.01474) and "On Calibration of Modern Neural Networks" actively replicate this idea of "95% of the time for large enough samples" and if anything we also extend them to a Bayesian setting. (And I don't even touch on works like "Stochastic Gradient Descent as Approximate Bayesian Inference".)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is (potentially) fine.  You are describing a simple version of [model averaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_averaging_(machine_learning)).  Of course, whether it is actually better in your case is an empirical question.

---

For what it's worth, "frequentist" doesn't really contrast with "machine learning".  In statistics, *frequentist* would contrast with *Bayesian*, but that distinction is orthogonal to this question.  You could contrast *statistics* with *machine learning* (many people do), but I think the distinction is somewhat forced and artificial, and at any rate, it's orthogonal to this question.

Comment: If you have a bunch of models, you can use boosting meta-algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boosting_(machine_learning)

Comment: +1, especially for the FWIW - IMHO ML is just computationally expensive statistics. ;o)